# What is the correct way to shuffle?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, shuffling

What is the correct way in terms of damage to the card/have a deck well shuffled for competitive tournaments, since you can make piles; I personally consider that the best way, just one for the game.

Comment: See https://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_mtr_21jan19_en.pdf §3.9 for the 'correct' rules, but it doesn't specify which technique (other than not using pile shuffling except for the start of the game).

Comment: There are a few other questions which could be used as a duplicate, but I'm not completely sure. https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5862/what-is-the-best-way-to-shuffle-a-large-deck-without-damaging-the-cards and https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/what-is-a-safe-and-accurate-technique-for-shuffling-cards are candidates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to shuffle a deck is to use multiple different methods of shuffling one after another. As the rules state pile shuffling can't be used except at the start of the game that is perhaps the best way to start your shuffle. After that the **Overhand Shuffle**, sliding a few cards at a time from one hand to the other so that the cards in each group stay in the same order but the group order is changed, effectively several small cuts. A **Riffle Shuffle**, taking two halves of the deck, bending them in the middle and letting them fall a card or two at a time onto eachother, does the best for reordering the deck, but since it involves bending the cards it also does damage to them over time, some people won't use this method because of it, and it should never be done to another person's cards for that reason. A similar effect to a riffle shuffle is the **Weave** or **Faro Shuffle** (not to be confused with mana weaving), where two halves of the deck are held with a little space between the edges of the cards for the other half's cards to slide into, this is easier with sleeves because the sleeves will create that space between the edges of the sleeves themselves. **Washing** the cards also does a pretty good job of randomizing, though it looks ridiculous and takes time to spread all the cards out face down and move them around randomly with your hands.

It's all a balance of the level of damage you're willing to accept to your cards, and the level of randomness needed. I will riffle my pauper deck but not my $1000+ EDH.

Comment: One thing to mention: "Washing" your cards could cause your deck to become "boxed", where the tops of the cards don't all align.  Since Magic backs are vertically and horizontally asymmetric, this could cause your deck to be considered "marked" in a tournament setting if you're not careful.  Sleeves don't help this problem, because sleeves are not vertically symmetric either (one side is open, the other is not).  Also, rubbing your unsleeved cards around on a table is probably the best possible way to damage them.

Comment: Also, FWIW I riffle shuffle my Legacy decks on a regular basis, so there's that :p

Comment: @Ertai87 I have never seen anyone consider cards being boxed as marked, though I suppose someone could be petty that way, or someone could intentionally box their land or something to abuse it. And as I said, it's all about the risks of damage you're willing to accept, I only have a few decks ever unsleeved, my pauper is the most notable, being less than $20 total.

Comment: Speaking as a certified judge, one of the things I look for when doing a deck check is, if I see a deck is boxed, I look for patterns in the boxing.  If I see a pattern, even if the pattern is unintentional, the deck is considered marked "with possibility of advantage" (note: "possibility of advantage" is the only justification required, not "intent to use advantage"), and you get a Game Loss, no questions asked (at Comp REL where IPG is in effect).  Don't box your deck, it's not worth it.

Comment: @Ertai87 I never really went into anything past PTQ level honestly so my experience is limited admittedly to that and being an organizer (Judge center responded to me when I tried to join)

Comment: PTQs (when they existed) were run at Comp REL, so you at least have Comp REL experience.  That said, many players who have played Comp REL don't know what that means.  Perhaps you never got deck checked when you boxed your deck, or perhaps the judge was just nice to you ;)

Comment: @Ertai87 I never did box my deck, since my preferred shuffles are alternating overhand and faro with a deck I won't riffle. just never seen it happen, I used to know the IPG a few years back when I was a rules adviser (when those existed) and was trying to become a judge, just never seen anyone really call anyone on boxed decks.

Comment: It doesn't happen often, because most people who box their decks do do it by accident and do not create a pattern (as discussed above).  However, the probability, when boxing your deck, that you do not create a pattern by accident, is nonzero, so just to protect yourself from getting a GL you do not deserve, the best practice is to just not box your deck at all.

Comment: Note that an overhand shuffle is not a meaningful shuffle--it takes ~1000 overhands to equal a single riffle or mash.

Answer (score 6):

### How to shuffle (theoretically)

[It takes 7 riffle shuffles to randomize a deck of (52) cards](https://www.nytimes.com/1990/01/09/science/in-shuffling-cards-7-is-winning-number.html).  If you're playing a 60 card format 7 riffle/mash shuffles are sufficient.  If you're playing commander which uses 100-card decks, you'll need to riffle shuffle 9 times to be randomized enough.  Shuffling more does make the deck more random, but 7 (or 9) iterations is enough in practice.

Pile "shuffling" does not randomize cards and is a waste of time.  Just perform more riffle shuffles instead.

### How to shuffle (physically)

Riffle shuffles are easy enough to do with practice.  You don't actually need to "bridge" the card as long as the cards are interleaving frequently and non-perfectly.  I often shuffle at the corners/sides and then just push the cards together.

As described in other answers, sleeved cards "mash" together easily to effectively replicate the mechanics of a riffle shuffle.  Cut the deck in half and push one half into the other block of cards.  They will naturally interleave, imitating a riffle shuffle.

If you play commander and need to shuffle 100-card behemoths, shuffling is harder.  Unsleeved (*gasp*) commander decks can still be riffle shuffled fairly easily.  And if you have large hands you might be able to mash shuffle a sleeved 100-card deck.  Otherwise, you'll have to get creative.  My best advice is to split the deck into two 50-card piles.  Then when you riffle/mash shuffle, shuffle together the top halves of each of the piles and repeat with the remaining bottoms.  Repeat 8 more times.

Comment: That "seven shuffles" figure gets repeated everywhere, but if you look at the [paper](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/bayer92.pdf) that's supposedly based on, you have to wonder if the reporter who first made that claim even bothered to read the abstract, because the first formula mentioned there gives us a value of >= 8.5 shuffles to mix up 52 cards (and even then, the formula is explicitly for "large" n, which 52 is not). The paper makes several *precise* claims, and often 7 is the *lower bound* where you start seeing significant improvement for various metrics.

Comment: Their main result seems to be that you need a certain minimum number of shuffles before it's even remotely mixed, and that after that point, each additional shuffle gives about half as much improvement as the one before. You can see where that minimum comes from by picturing what happens to the bottom card on the deck after n shuffles. Assuming we cut perfectly each time, and *always* shuffle it on top of its corresponding card, we roughly double the maximum number of cards that can be beneath it after each shuffle, and it takes 6+ shuffles before it can *possibly* reach the top of the deck.

Comment: @Ray you're free to write your own answer with your own insights into the actual math.  "Random enough" is the metric that the reporting on this topic uses.  And it's good enough for me too.

Comment: I'm not objecting to "random enough" as a metric. I'm saying that article you link cites the Bayer Diaconis paper as its entire support for the idea that seven shuffles *is* random enough, but that isn't what the paper actually says.  I'm objecting to the shoddy reporting in the article.

Comment: @Ray Complain to the NY Times instead?

Answer (score 5):

1) "Pile shuffling" is not actually shuffling, in that it doesn't randomize your deck.  Let's say you have a deck of 60 cards and you number the cards 1-60.  Then you "pile shuffle" those 60 cards into 8 piles and number those piles 1-8.  Then you know for a fact that card 1 is at the bottom of pile 1, card 2 is at the bottom of pile 2, and so on, and you know that card 9 is second from the bottom of pile 1, then card 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, and 57.  Since you deterministically know the order of the cards in each pile, this method is not considered randomization, and is therefore not "shuffling".  This is why judges (and some players, thankfully) have begun to call the method "pile counting"; it is an efficient method of counting the cards in your deck to make sure you haven't lost any, but that's all.

2) As a result of point 1), you are not allowed to "pile shuffle" your deck in a tournament for the purpose of randomization.  You are allowed to do it for the purpose of counting, but you still need to shuffle thoroughly afterwards.

3) As for an actual answer to your question, the answer is "use sleeves".  If you use sleeves, damaging your card through standard mash shuffling is very uncommon, and mash shuffling is the most efficient way to shuffle, in that you are shuffling a random number of cards from the deck into random positions in the remainder of the deck.  Since you may not fully randomize the bottom few cards of the deck using a mash shuffle, you should also use other shuffling methods such as overhand shuffle.  Personally, I haven't found bridge (riffle) shuffles to damage my cards all that much, as long as you don't angle your bridge too high and bend the cards too much.

4) As an addendum to "use sleeves", sleeves can sometimes rip during a mash shuffle and the sharp edge of the sleeve could nick the card inside of the broken sleeve.  In which case, you can use perfect-fit sleeves ("inner sleeves") inside of your normal sleeves.  Then when the outer sleeve would nick your card, instead it nicks your inner sleeve and keeps your card safe.  I've never damaged a card using a mash shuffle when my deck was "double-sleeved" (using both regular sleeves and inner sleeves).

Comment: Is it acceptable to pile out your cards, then riffle or mash the individual piles together, in a cumulative fashion?

Comment: @MattEllen Yes, that would be considered a "shuffle".  However, the "pile" part of this "shuffle" is not considered part of the "shuffle" itself.  Also, a judge may restrict you from piling out your cards more than once per game, as such a process is both time-consuming and not effective for randomization.